# Changing the size of table popup menu when you press the tableMenuButton (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

When I click on tableMenuButton popup menu appears.

[image]
If then I click the button again, the menu will be the size of less unnoticed.

[image]
Third push the original size of the menu is resumed.

Is it possible to eliminate the ugly visual effect?

Edit:

I found a place in the code where lies the trigger enable this error!
Now I have the following situation in the code. At the instance of the entire application set css file in start() method

```
 StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet("css/general.css");
```

But there is a form in which I want to redefine the style of the specific stage and put a different style.

```
showStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add("css/my.css");
```

The most interesting is that the contents of these files, css does not matter. I checked today and really checked even empty files cause a similar effect on the table. When I turn it override all the table becomes normal.

Comment: never seen it, which version are you using? And please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @kleopatra i have seen also this behavior when closing popup and then reopening it.Even with `JavaFX 8`,actually it might be a bug or a strange behavior.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me - no help possible without a SSCCE (while interested to see it, I'm definitely NOT going to write my own test ;-)